# How to resolve the "file 1 needs media recovery" error in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-11g

I am trying to migrate oracle 11g database from Windows to a Linux server. I have followed these steps for migration:

1. I have opened database in mount mode.
2. Then I have backed up file on the Windows machine using `rman`.
3. Then I have created pfile from sfile.
4. I have used winscp to move my file to the Linux server.
5. Then I have copied DBF files to `u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/oradata/orcl/`, `initORCL.ora` to `u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/dbs` and `transport.sql` to `tmp/orcl`
6. I have changed all paths in pfile as per new location on the Linux server.
7. Now when I am running `@/tmp/orcl/TRANSPORT.SQL` it show this error:

   ```
   ALTER DATABAE OPEN RESETLOGS; 
   *
   ERROR at line 1: ORA-01194: file 1 needs media recovery 
   ORA-01110: data file 1: 'u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/oradata/orcl/\SYSTEM01.DBF'
   ```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: May I know what you are trying to achieve? are you doing refresh of a database using rman? or your trying to refresh a database using cold backup which is very feasible way.

Comment: trying to refresh a database using cold backup

Comment: then in that case you need to bring down entire database and start moving all the datafiles to desired location and start the database. there are lot of sites available in google to do cold backup. Here it is i took a randomly 
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2183982/steps-for-cold-backup